# React Native Image Slider Animation

Tags: react-native, react-native-animatable

There are 4 images. Whenever I swap them, I want to have a smooth animated transition. How may I apply that in my current code?

[Click here to view the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHYp8.png)

Also please check out the 2nd screenshot. I don't want the left swap option to be active when there is no image. But it swaps 1 extra time and stops. What is wrong with my logic?

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtLe6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with the below code:

```
const handleSwipeLeft = () => {
    if (activeImg < totalImage - 1) {
        setActiveImage(currActive => currActive + 1)
    }
}
```

as the length greater than the index.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jignesh Mayani. Do you have any idea about the animation issue?

Comment: Let me check again

Comment: What the issue you are facing in the sliding?

Comment: I wrapped everything inside Animatew.View tag. But not sure about the exact CSS properties or animation properties that can make a smooth transition while swapping the images. ( I am a beginner in react native and learning).  Check out the screenshot please https://prnt.sc/1b2o2nu

Comment: You can use libraries like a carousel which have a heavy user base and will give you a better management for sliding views